# Json array object undefined value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get an array of object from php with ajax request.

Until now all is ok, i get my array in json format in my ajax response in javascript `{"ID:"9348","Name":"Mark"}`.

But now if i try to get the object with `alert(data["ID"])`

```html
$.ajax({
   url:'loaddata.php',
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data){
    
    alert(data['ID']);
   },
    error: function (thrownError) {
    alert("errore");
   }
  });
```

i get "`undefined`"   Can anybody help me ???

---

in my php file i have this:

```html
$a=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 $a[] = json_encode (array('ID'=>$row['ID'],'name'=>$row['name']));
 
}
   header("Content-Type: application/json");
   echo json_encode($a);
```

Comment: Can you try with data.ID?

Comment: It would probably help if you  would `console.dir(data)` so that you could see what the object really looks like. @ssola if there really isn't an "ID" property that will make no difference at all; if there is, then the OP code would work.

Comment: @Pointy he already said was returning an object with the ID property... so should be there. Obviously if the complete response is wrong then it's a different issue.

Comment: @ssola if that really were the case then there'd be no need to ask the question because the code in the OP would have worked.

Comment: if you copy & pasted the json correctly then the json is invalid: `{"ID:"9348","Name":"Mark"}.`  there is a `"` missing after ID. Protip: Use the debugger of the browser (every browser has one). it is really really REALLY useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are double encoding

```
in-loop: $a[] = json_encode (... // this makes $a an array of json-strings
outside: echo json_encode($a ... // this echos an JSON representation of an array of json-strings
```

this will not work, just produce/gather your array, then at the end do `json_encode` *once*

- unless you really want JSON-Strings inside your JSON-Object/Array

Answer (score 0):

From the php code you posted it seems that you return an array. therefor you have to select the dataset by array index:

`alert(data[0]['ID']);`

and your json probably looks like this:

`[ {"ID":"9348","Name":"Mark"}, ... ]`